# Highlighting/marking/copying/deleting same text in multiple locations

Tags: tables

I was making a table. I wanted all cells in some columns to be gray, but not the top cell. Did this the hard way with \cellcolor for every cell, until I realised I can just make my columns grey, and then overwrite the top cells with \rowcolor.

Editing my mistake, I would like to remove alle the \cellcolor input. As I highlight the code, I see that overleaf shows me all the places in my code with the same code. My question is: Is there an easy way to now select all the similar text, and then to delete at the same time?

As picture 1 shows, I've highlighted the first one (in the most blue color), and all the same ones turn in to a lighter blue color.

[image: Picture 1]

Comment: `Alt+F3` is the way to go -- for sublime text

Comment: Using a Mac, by the way. I tried Alt+F3 (option button being the equivalent to alt), without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Holding down control + option, and then pressing right arrow allows you to select the next light blue marked object (on Mac). Very useful!